# How to change studio light image via python script?

Tags: python, light, lighting

In the editor, I find the following commands:

```
bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'RENDERED'
bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'MATERIAL'
bpy.context.space_data.shading.studio_light = 'sunrise.exr'
```

can you suggest me how to translate it in a functioning python script?

Comment: I beg your pardon? That is functioning Python script.

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'SpaceTextEditor' object has no attribute 'shading'

Comment: Ahh. U R running this from the text editor, so the context is incorrect. You need to get the 3D editor space directly.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it via code?

Comment: Will look into it..